# Mirror my iPad 2 screen on my Windows PC?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, windows, airplay, screen-sharing

I can't find any app which mirrors my iPad's screen to my Windows computer screen. Since iDisplay has been removed from the App Store I have no other ideas. Any recomendations (up to $15) for a solution to mirror my iPad screen on my Windows PC display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out [Reflector by Air Squirrels](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/).

It works very well on the Mac, has a windows version and also appears to have a trial version. You can make sure it works before spending money on a license.

Comment: I use Reflector for precisely this, and it works fabulously.

Comment: i found airserver and used it but reflector seems to do the same! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try annotate.net. It works on both PC and Mac has a full featured 7 day free trial and even after the expiration of the trial, allows u 10 minutes of free Airplay indefinitely. Can be used across multiple computers unlike Airserver or Reflector which is tied to a single computer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use following:
http://www.x-mirage.com/x-mirage/
That helps a lot during development and testing