# Mirror iPad Pro screen to my Windows 10 PC via USB

Tags: ipad, windows, software-recommendation, airplay, screen-sharing

I need to mirror my iPad screen to my windows 10 computer without wifi (via USB). Is there a modern software solution that does not involve very low framerate or high latency ?

Answer (score 0):

The good folks at Air Squirrels have the software that’s the closest to your request. [I have used them in the past, was delighted by the previous version of their Reflector app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135441/5472) and it looks like they have a trial version so you can be sure of the value before buying it.

- https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/try

Since you require USB, be sure your non WiFi networking works before you invest if that’s the key factor for you. Reverse tethering works for Macs out of the box so hopefully this is close enough for windows.